# VBA ADO Recordset 'Hanging' in Task Scheduler, but NOT Hanging on Console

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

A batch file launches msAccess.exe with "/x Macro" to run a macro that opens a form, fills in values on the form, runs a report printing to .RTF, sends the .RTF via email, then quits msAccess. When the batch file is run from the console it runs fine. When the batch file is run as a Scheduled Task it hangs.

It hangs on the rsA.Open:

```
Set rsA = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
s1 = "SELECT * FROM ConfigData WHERE [Key]='TaskID'"
rsA.Open s1, MaxDat, , adLockPessimistic, adCmdText
```

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by running from the Console? Is it VBScript or VBA?

Comment: Is TaskID supposed to be a variable? Because then you'll have to change it to `s1 = "SELECT * FROM ConfigData WHERE [Key]='" & TaskID & "'"`. Maybe that'll help?